# How can I remove the quote marks and retrieve the list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, python-itertools

I have a list as a string like this:

```
"['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Brazil']"
```

I want to retrieve the list from the string, like this:

```
['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Brazil']
```

How can I do that? Itertools or list function have not given me the proper result. 
Thanks

Comment: actually `"["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]"` is not a python string. I think you're trying to say that your string is `'["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]'` with double `'`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus My bad. It's fixed now.

Comment: @ChihebNexus I know what is your mean. BUT, if there has a file `data.log`, which content is `"["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]"`. How to deal with it?

Comment: @CHENJIAN In that case you need to parse your data and replace the external `"` by `'` otherwise you'll have a not valid python strings. One way to do it is using `regex`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus One more step than this question. I get it and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can evaluate the string to a list using `eval`:

```
 eval('["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]')
```

Executing this on python shell, gives a list:

```
>>> eval('["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]')
['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Brazil']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am such a noob. I completely forgot about eval and was panicking. Thanks again.

Comment: @0x1, You are welcome. If this answer your question, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: @ChihebNexus, having to evalute is bad by design. It's absolutely not recommended to design a software that works this way. But, I don't have all the context of the software so I gave a quick n dirty answer.

Comment: @MedAli Yes. Otherwise, your answer is correct for this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `literal_eval` from `ast` module like this example:

```
from ast import literal_eval as le
data = le('["USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Brazil"]')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Brazil']
```

Also, don't use `eval()`, use `literal_eval()` instead. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/3926995) for more details.

Comment: That's enlightening. I had no idea. Thanks!